# Imprimir diferentes precios en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo este codigo en C# windowsform, si tengo un switch , como hago que al seleccionar un case del switch me imprima un costo diferente.

**Ejemplo**

case 1:
 Modelo_Auto = "Acura";

Costo $13000

Modelo_Auto = "Tesla";

Costo $20000

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.modelo();

    }

      int Marca = 0;
    private string Modelo_Auto = string.Empty;
    public void modelo()
    {
        Marca = cmb_Marca.SelectedIndex + 1;
        switch (Marca)
        {
            case 1:
                Modelo_Auto = "Acura";
                break;
            case 2:
                Modelo_Auto = "Alfa Romeo";
                break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo quieres utilizar en otra parte, es necesario crear una variable para el costo, otra cosa no es necesario utlizar un +1 en tu selectedIndex, puedes inicializarlo en 0 igual que un combobox

```
double Costo = 0f;

    private void cmb_Marca_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               Marca = cmb_Marca.SelectedIndex;
               switch (Marca)
               {
                   case 0:
                       Modelo_Auto = "Acura";
                       Costo = 13000;
                       break;
                   case 1:
                       Modelo_Auto = "Alfa Romeo";
                       Costo = 20000;
                       break;
               }
               MessageBox.Show(Costo.ToString("N"));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

dentro del mismo Case tienes que poner las instrucciones que quieras que se hagan, si por imprimir te refieres a que se muestre un mensaje puedes poner:

```html
switch (Marca)
        {
            case 1:
                Modelo_Auto = "Acura";
                MessageBox.Show("El valor es de $13000");
                break;
            case 2:
                Modelo_Auto = "Alfa Romeo";
                MessageBox.Show("El valor es de $20000");
                break;
```

Si quieres que a ese valor que indicas le saque el 19%:

```html
switch (Marca)
        {
            case 1:
                Modelo_Auto = "Acura";
                MessageBox.Show("El valor es de $13000");
                double x = 13000*0.19;
                MessageBox.Show("El 19% de $13000 es: "+x.toString());
                break;
            case 2:
                Modelo_Auto = "Alfa Romeo";
                MessageBox.Show("El valor es de $20000");
                double y = 20000*0.19;
                MessageBox.Show("El 19% de $20000 es: "+x.toString());
                break;
```

Para el *case* 1, asigno un nombre a la variable, después en un messagebox muestro un mensaje, hago una operación matemática, muestro un mensaje mostrando el resultado.

Es cosa de ir viendo que necesitas que ocurra cuando el **case** sea 1 o 2 o N.

Espero que esto se sirva de ejemplo para lo que necesitas hacer.
Saludos