# Imprimir diferentes precios en c# switch

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo este codigo en C# windowsform, si tengo DOS switch , me imprima un costo diferente.Es decir si selcciono un combobox y despues otro combobox y dependiendo la combinacion me imprima un costo distinto.

```
    public void año()
        {
            Año = cmb_Año.SelectedIndex + 0;
            switch (Año)
            {
                case 1:
                    Auto_Año = "2020";
                    total = 50;
                    break;

    public void modelo()
{

    switch (Marca)

            {
                case 1:
                   Modelo_Auto = "Acura";
                    total = 21;
                    break;
}
```

[image: Como se muestra en la imgen cuando el usuario haga una combinación entre los combo box salga un precio distinto]

Comment: Pero todo ese codigo esta mal y no compila. Podes explicar mucho mejor que pasa?

Comment: Como se muestra en la imgen cuando el usuario haga una combinación entre los combo box salga un precio distinto

Comment: Y que tiene que ver el codigo que no compila que esta ahi arriba con eso? o sea, cual es tu problema especifico con eso?

Comment: Ya habías preguntado algo parecido [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243482/imprimir-diferentes-precios-en-c). Qué es lo que no te sirvió de esa respuesta? Porque la marcaste como respondida...